# Method isEmpty for binary tree issue

Tags: java, binary-tree, is-empty

I am trying to write myself the isEmpty method for a binary tree but I am having a problem. So this is the method that I am using.

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
if(root == null) return true;
else return false;
}
```

When I add only one element, and then remove this element, and call isEmpty, I do not get true, but false.

Is there somethng wrong with my implementation?

---

So this is the remove method:

```
  /**
    * Internal method to remove from a subtree.
    * @param x the item to remove.
    * @param t the node that roots the tree.
    * @return the new root.
    * @throws ItemNotFoundException if x is not found.
    */
    protected BinaryNode<AnyType> remove( AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
    {
    if( t == null )
    throw new ItemNotFoundException( x.toString( ) );
    if( x.compareTo( t.element ) < 0 )
    t.left = remove( x, t.left );
    else if( x.compareTo( t.element ) > 0 )
    t.right = remove( x, t.right );
    else if( t.left != null && t.right != null ) // Two children
    {
    t.element = findMin( t.right ).element;
    t.right = removeMin( t.right );
    }
    else
    t = ( t.left != null ) ? t.left : t.right;
    return t;
    }
```

and this is the removeMin method that the remove method uses:

```
        /**
         * Internal method to remove minimum item from a subtree.
         * @param t the node that roots the tree.
         * @return the new root.
         * @throws ItemNotFoundException if t is empty.
         */
         protected BinaryNode<AnyType> removeMin( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
         {
         if( t == null )
        throw new ItemNotFoundException( );
        else if( t.left != null )
        {
        t.left = removeMin( t.left );
        return t;
        }
        else
        return t.right;
        }
```

Comment: I think problem is in remove function. This looks ok.

Comment: The `isEmpty` method is right. It would be great if you show us the `remove` method.

Comment: This isn't the cause of your problem but you can just `return root==null;`

Comment: The remove function works fine. I have also unit tested it.

Comment: The method should really look like this, although it is only good practice: public boolean isEmpty() { return root == null; }

Comment: If the remove function works fine then why isn't `root` null?

Comment: @user1181847 I wonder why you return `BinaryNode<AnyType>` when you must remove it (nullify it) and return the `AnyType` element.

Comment: because I keep those as inner methods, and I call them from my public methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your remove element code. Usually than code find out parent of remove node and set to null corresponding reference. And for last element it have to set to null `root` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `remove(AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t)` method searchs the node with X element and replace it by one of its children with the `removeMin` method (in case it has 2 children) or with the left or the right child node. Your public remove method could be something like this:

```
public boolean remove(AnyType x) {
    try {
        BinaryNode<AnyType> node = remove(x, root);
        if (node != null) {
            node = null;
            return true;
        }
        return fal
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do something with the exception
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: still does not work. when I try to remove the element entered first, the isEmpty still is false, which means that the root is not set to null yet.

Comment: have you made some debug and checked that root and node have the same value when your tree has only 1 element?